# Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataContentTypeException: A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, rest, odata

I'm getting following exception

```
Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataContentTypeException: 
A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content 
type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 
'application/atom+xml;type=entry, application/atom+xml, application/json;odata=verbose' 
matches the content type 'application/json'.
     at Microsoft.Data.OData.MediaTypeUtils.GetFormatFromContentType....
```

using code

```
var someJason = "{'__metadata':{'type':'SP.Data.TestObjectItem'}, " + jsonProperties + "}";
var content = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someJason));
content.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigest);

var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, queryUrl);
httpRequestMessage.Content = content;
httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(),
                               "application/json;odata=verbose");
httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(),
                               "application/json;odata=verbose");
var result = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

`result` variable is always returning 400 'Bad Request'. I wasn't able to find any header values that would force this code to use allowed content type. In some cases, when i set some total rubbish in Accept header, i'm getting 406 'Not Acceptable' which totally fits to  http://www.odata.org/documentation/operations documentation.

According to this odata documentation, i was trying to set also query string to either `$format=JSON` and `$format=atom`, but i've never noticed any difference with this parameter (seems like it's being ignored).

So my question is - what I'm missing?

Code is used in WinRT application which calls SharePoint 2013 OData service (_api/web/lists/), but I think (and hope) that problem isn't that specific.

Comment: Can you try to capture an HTTP trace (Fiddler can do that for sure). Looking at the code it looks OK, but it's what's on the wire which counts.